# Firebase Cloud Function undefined request query parameters from Android App

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I have this Firebase Cloud Function:

```js
exports.verifyToken = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  const token = req.query.token;
  console.log("token: " + token);
  return firebaseAdmin
    .auth()
    .createCustomToken(token, {provider: 'TEST'})
    .then((firebaseToken) => {
      console.log("Returning firebase token to user: " + firebaseToken);
      return res.json({firebase_token: firebaseToken});
    });
});
```

And this is my android code:

```kotlin
return Single.create<String> { emitter ->
  val token = authToken.accessToken
  val data = HashMap<String, String>()
  data.put("token", token)

  FirebaseFunctions.getInstance()
    .getHttpsCallable("verifyToken")
    .call(data)
    .continueWith { task ->
      return@continueWith task.result?.data as String
    }
    .addOnSuccessListener { firebaseToken ->
      emitter.onSuccess(firebaseToken)
    }
    .addOnFailureListener {
      emitter.onError(it)
    }
}
```

When I try to run the cloud function via firebase emulator and Postman, it works fine. The function was able to get the value of `token`. But whenever I do it via Android, I get this from the Firebase Functions Logs:

```
4:29:40.837 AM
verifyToken
Function execution started
4:29:41.411 AM
verifyToken
token: undefined         //<--- this here says that the token is undefined.
4:29:41.554 AM
verifyToken
Unhandled rejection
4:29:41.560 AM
verifyToken
Error: `uid` argument must be a non-empty string uid. at FirebaseAuthError.FirebaseError [as constructor] (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:43:28) at FirebaseAuthError.PrefixedFirebaseError [as constructor] (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:89:28) at new FirebaseAuthError (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:148:16) at FirebaseTokenGenerator.createCustomToken (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/auth/token-generator.js:233:19) at Auth.BaseAuth.createCustomToken (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/auth/auth.js:96:36) at /workspace/index.js:25:6 at cloudFunction (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/providers/https.js:51:16) at /layers/google.nodejs.functions-framework/functions-framework/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-framework/build/src/invoker.js:100:17 at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:79:11)
4:29:41.562 AM
verifyToken
Function execution took 725 ms, finished with status: 'crash'
```

If you have noticed, the code is almost similar to what Firebase has in their getting started pages. But then it doesn't fully work on my end.

- I have already checked with my `google-services.json` and it's already updated.
- I am currently set as the owner of the project, so no issues with `firebase deploy`
- I also have the `service-account.json` updated and included with the firebase functions.

I might have missed something in my code or configuration. Any inputs are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not possible to use the Firebase Functions SDK to invoke `onRequest` type functions.  The Firebase SDK implements the client side of a [callable function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable) that you declare with `onCall`.  You're using `onRequest` here, which means you're writing a standard HTTP type function.  For that type of function, you should use a standard HTTP client (not the Firebase SDK).  If you actually did want to use the Firebase SDK to invoke your function, you will have to write a callable function instead.  Note that callable functions [have their own spec](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable-reference), and you won't be able to easily invoke them from postman.